# Compiling with Maven from VS Code doesn't catch errors

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Maven plugin from VS Code to compile my java sources and I'm observing a very strange behavior. Let me try to show you the steps I'm following:

- start a shell
- modify a .java file, adding a clear syntax error (I'm adding "foo" just after the imports)
- run "/usr/bin/mvn" install -f "pom.xml"
- the compiler catches the error

so far so good, then

- start VS Code
- open the command palette, select Maven, then the project and finally compile
- i can see from the terminal inside VS Code that it is calling quite the same command I run previously from the shell, but now it says "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date" so no error is catched
- now if I run the same command from the shell it behaviors exactly as in VS Code (doesn't recompile anything)
- if I force a date change on the java file last access (with "touch") nothing changes.
- if I close VS Code, then again "touch" the java file and run the command from the shell, now it gets it need to recompile the file and eventually catches the error

Can anyone help me to understand what the hell is happening? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not familiar with VS Code but did you... save the file?  Not trying to be snarky, I've made that error countless times in STS and seen similar behaviour.  Also a `mvn clean install` forces a recompile.

Comment: yes the files was saved, also using "touch" its access time was updated. Running clean install force the build of the entire module, but I don't want to rebuild every source code every time

Comment: to clarify confusion: Where is this java file? what/how is your directory structure? (where do you open shell/`code`?)

Comment: the java file is in a src folder (while the generated class are in a target folder)

Comment: I can "reproduce" so far as: when an already compiled class is in place (target folder), then invalidating the java file+`mvn install` will have no effect! ...`mvn clean install` will. (IDE independent)

Comment: yes specifying clean force to rebuild all java files and then it behave as it is supposed to, but that's shouldn't be done all time I think

Comment: @xerx593 it works as I expect to using NetBeans. Also, it seams VS Code is simply executing on the terminal the command "mvn compile" (or mvn install) specifing the pom.xml file of the project. If I run the same command on a shell it works as expected. Note that VS Code seems to invalidate the process for all other tools too, so to try with other IDE close VS Code and run a mvn clean before trying to reproduce

Comment: Amazing: Netbeans seems to do something!! (can also reproduce: having project/file (only) opened in netbeans (compile on save: off) - will "always" behave "correct" (vscode, other editor) ...as soon closing netbeans: i can reproduce yesterdays comment  (with any editor)

Comment: here is [the condition](https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/564eda0953421abbc9d6aee70feddc7ef13ed4de/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/AbstractCompilerMojo.java#L831) of maven-compiler-plugin (to log "Changes detected"/"Nothing to compile")

Comment: ..i "guess" it is one (or both!?:) of the two latter: `|| isSourceChanged(compilerConfiguration, compiler ) || incrementalBuildHelper.inputFileTreeChanged(incrementalBuildHelperRequest )` ..but how/where: is a good question!+1 and probably a maven bug/feature!?

Comment: But! (LOL) opening netbeans doesn't fix it (as expected, in opposite: netbeans now also behaves wrong), i have to clean! ;(;(;(

Comment: so "compile-on-save" + *restart/reload* (of netbeans/project) have also (side) effect!

Comment: it seems that something is preventing this condition `isSourceChanged(compilerConfiguration, compiler )` to trigger the compilation of the modified java file...